# Substring from last index

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, substring

```
ABC:123 UVW XYZ NN-000
```

What is the best method to get the value after the last space using `substr()`? In this case I want to get `NN-000` but also be able to get that last value in the case that it's greater than or less than 6 characters.

Comment: what do you mean by "but also be able to get that last value in the case that it's **greater** than or **less** than 6 characters"

Comment: @pratik gard, the string after the last space can be more or less than 6 characters in length. `NN-00` `NN-000` `NN-0000` so I don't want to select using substring for the last 6 characters.

Comment: In Oracle `regexp_substr(your_string, '\S*$')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you could use [`reverse`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) and [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select data, 
  rv, 
  reverse(substring_index(rv, ' ', 1)) yd
from
(
  select data,
    reverse(data) rv
  from yt
) d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c91c95/1)

In Oracle you could use [`reverse`](http://psoug.org/definition/REVERSE.htm), [`substr`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) and [`instr`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php):

```
select data, 
  reverse(substr(rv, 0, instr(rv, ' '))) rv
from
(
  select data, reverse(data) rv
  from yt
) d
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d893a/3)

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` functions

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ABC:123 UVW XYZ NN-000', INSTR('ABC:123 UVW XYZ NN-000', ' ', -1)) 
AS LASTOCCUR
FROM DUAL
```

***RESULT:***

```
| LASTOCCUR |
-------------
|    NN-000 |
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11924)**

Answer (score 1):

Combine the powers of RIGHT(),REVERSE() AND LOCATE()

```
SELECT RIGHT('ABC:123 UVW XYZ NN-000',LOCATE(' ',REVERSE('ABC:123 UVW XYZ NN-000'))-1)
```

EDIT: Locate in MYSQL, not CHARINDEX

REVERSE() reverses the string, so that the 'first' space it finds is really the last one.  You could use SUBSTRING instead of RIGHT, but if what you're after is at the end of the string, might as well use RIGHT.